# Unspecified template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to use templates with multiple to pass data onto a function, but using only the first template argument as a filter. Something like this:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class Component {

};

template <typename A>
class Context {
    public:
        void add(Component<A, void *> comp) {
        }
}

typedef struct Foo { int x; } Foo;
typedef struct Bar { int y; } Bar;
Context<Foo> *context = new Context<Foo>();
Component<Foo, Bar> *comp = new Component<Foo, Bar>();
context->add(comp); // error
```

But the compiler complains that it cannot convert `Component<Foo, Bar>` to `Component<Foo, void *>`. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you probably need to do is change the signature of the 'add' method:

```
template <typename A>
class Context
{
public:
  template<class B>
  void add(Component<A, B> comp)
  {           
  }
};
```

However, I don't know the details of your problem so this is a mere guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add a converting copy constructor to your `Component`:

```
template<class U, class V>
Component(Component<U,V> const& other){
  // ...
};
```

But that is still refineable with the appropriate `enable_if` SFINAE guard:

```
// <tr1/type_traits> for C++03
#include <type_traits> // for C++0x

template<class T, class U>
struct can_convert{
  // std::tr1::... for C++03
  static bool const value =
      std::is_same<T,U>::value || std::is_convertible<T,U>::value;
};

template<class C1, class C2>
struct ice_and{
  static bool const value = C1::value && C2::value;
}

// define for clarity and brevity
#define IF_CAN_CONVERT(A,B,U,V) \
  typename std::enable_if<ice_and<can_convert<A,U>,can_convert<B,V> > >::type* = 0

template<class U, class V>
Component(Component<U,V> const& other, IF_CAN_CONVERT(A,B,U,V)){
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to use templates with multiple to pass data onto a function, but using only the first template argument as a filter.  [...] But the compiler complains that it cannot convert Component to Component. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Well, your filter works doesn't it: your `add` function will only match a Component whose second template parameter is `void*`, and you're providing `Bar`.  What else could you possibly expect?  If you want it to handle other "second-parameters" as well, either remove the filter, provide an fallback function for it to match, or some kind of conversion.